# How to display image from selected id

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm trying to display the info of the user when I get the id using `$routeParams.id`, I already displayed the user's info using texts only but how can I display the user's image using `img src`?

**In my controller I did this to get the selected user.**

```
.controller('editbloodrequestCtrl', function($scope,$routeParams, Bloodrequest) {
var app = this;
     Bloodrequest.getBloodrequest($routeParams.id).then(function(data) {
        if (data.data.success) {              
            $scope.newLastname = data.data.bloodrequest.lastname; 
            $scope.newFirstname = data.data.bloodrequest.firstname; 
            $scope.newImg = data.data.bloodrequest.img; 
            app.currentUser = data.data.bloodrequest._id; 
        } else {
            app.errorMsg = data.data.message; 
        }
    });
});
```

**Now that I get the users info, I displayed this in my frontend**

```
<label>Lastname:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="newLastname">

<label>Firstname:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="newFirstname">

<label>Image:</label>
<img src ="" name="img" ng-model="newImg"> //how can I display the image here?
```

**Sample Documents:**

```
 {firstname:"James",lastname:"Reid",img:"random.jpg"}
```

**My output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to bind ng-model to your image, just use the src with the absolute path of the image

```
<img src ="{{newImg}}" name="img">
```

Comment: nice! but how can I display the image if it is an array? do i need an ng-repeat?

Comment: thanks! working now, will be accepting your answer in 7n mins

Answer (score 0):

No need to bind ng-model to your image, just use the src with the absolute path of the image..ng-model using only input tags.

```
<img ng-src ="newImg" name="newimg" />
```